# How to find and replace a path name within a file in Perl

Tags: r, perl

Im working from R, but I think this is really a Perl issue. I'd like to replace the string `file1=""` with the pathname (including double quotes)
`"/User/me/ct.txt"` which is in the file `called User/read/book/tbb.conf. I'd like to do this using perl.

So far I have

```
 system(paste("perl -i -p -e's/file= {/User/me/ct.txt}/g' /Users/read/book/tbb.conf"))
```

but this is giving me the error

```
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.
```

Comment: What have you read that suggests that `s/...` pattern would work? Google `perl replacement string` and the [first](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=98357) [three](http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html) [hits](http://www.htmlite.com/perl025c.php) are perfectly relevant and helpful in crafting a better expression. Things to consider: proper syntax of the `s/.../g` command, and escaping slashes.

Comment: I've tried to improve your question, but I may have made things worse! Your `perl` command `s/file= {/User/me/ct.txt}/g `is puzzling as it has a substitution that requires a *pattern* and a *replacement*, separated by slashes; but (ignoring the slashes in the path) you provide only one value. Please check and write it more clearly, giving an example.

Comment: I think I have provided both values already? I want to find the string file= and then I want to replace that string with /User/me/ct.txt. I'm not sure how I can make this clearer. Perhaps you have voted it down because you haven't read it properly? I can assure you that reading a google answer is easier than asking a question here so obvs is done before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
system(paste("perl -i -p -e's{file1=\"\"}{/User/me/ct.txt}g' /Users/read/book/tbb.conf"))
```

You see the `s/FIND/REPLACE/OPTIONS` can also be written like:

```
s{FIND}{REPLACE}OPTIONS
```

Your example was missing the braces around the search expression.

If `R` dosen't let you escape the embedded quotes, you can use `\x22` for each quote. But I bet you might need to ESCAPE the back slash one or more times.
(ahh the joys of shell in the middle)

Comment: Thanks so much. An extremely helpful answer. I didnt need the \x22 in the end just your code. Thanks again